# Installation issues

Tags: config, database

When I go to install Craft everything appears to install properly.  It creates all the db tables, but then after going to the CP it displays "Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php."  Even though during the install process it could connect just fine.  Anybody run into this?  Craft Version 2.1.2569

Comment: Hi @th3mus1cman, welcome to Craft SE! Since this appears to have been an isolated incident with no useful historical value, I'm going to close it as a "bug report" (which isn't completely accurate, but close enough).

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Local MySQL problem. #facepalm

Comment: Hi @th3mus1cman, would you mind telling me what MySQL issue it was? Having a similar problem.